# SaltStack: Push single change, not all

Tags: saltstack

I have a server which was managed by hand before.
We want to manage this server with saltstack in the future.

I run this to see what you current salt formular would do:

```
salt-ssh remote-host state.sls webserver test=True
```

There are several changes.

I would like to push (apply) some of the changes, but not all.

For example I see the output of this, and I would like to apply this, but no other change should get applied:

---

```
      ID: server.conf
Function: file.managed
    Name: /etc/apache2/vhosts.d/server.conf
  Result: None
 Comment: The file /etc/apache2/vhosts.d/server.conf is set to be changed
 Changes:   
          ----------
          diff:
              --- 
              +++ 
              @@ -13,43 +13,17 @@

              - old_stuff
              + new_stuff
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[salt.sls_id](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.state.html#salt.modules.state.sls_id) is in theory what you're looking for.
It works for salt master/minion and masterless but I've just noticed it doesn't work with salt-ssh

EDIT: see [Issue #44733](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/44733)

EDIT2: it's coming in [2017.7.3](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/pull/44659)!

Comment: Sad, this one (sls_id) looked close to a great solution. Thank you -

Comment: rmarchei  at github is you? Thank you very much!

Comment: yeah that was me!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a individual sls (here my-change.sls) file for the change and just call it:

`salt remote-host state.apply my-change test=true`